# Oracle SQL - List Results into a single row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to return rows grouped by T.ID for status counts in to a single row output for the T.ID

I have tried to use LISTAGG but get tied up in knots with errors around the grouping.

The basic SQL is this:

```
SELECT T.ID ,T.STATUS ||':'||COUNT(T.STATUS)||'; '
  FROM TRANSACTION T
  GROUP BY T.STATUS, T.ID;
```

So this returns many rows (as expected) but I want the returns with the same T.ID to return a single row like this:

| ID | RESULTS |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | C:1 |
| 1231 | C:2, S:3, E:1 |

Comment: A [mcve] would make this clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate twice - first using `ID` and `STATUS` to generate the counts and then, second, to aggregate all the statuses and counts for each `ID`:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       LISTAGG(status || ':' || status_count, ', ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY status) AS results
FROM   (
  SELECT ID,
         STATUS,
         COUNT(STATUS) AS status_count
  FROM   TRANSACTION
  GROUP BY
         ID,
         STATUS
)
GROUP BY
       ID;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE transaction (ID, status) AS
  SELECT 1000, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1231, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1231, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1231, 'S' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1231, 'S' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1231, 'S' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1231, 'E' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | RESULTS |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | C:1 |
| 1231 | C:2, E:1, S:3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7VAPv9j1)